# CSS: how to keep styles after focus is removed

Tags: css, angularjs, button, focus

We have some buttons that are styled with the following CSS:

```
.btn-outline-primary {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

    .btn-outline-primary:hover,
    .btn-outline-primary:focus {
      background: blue;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      color: white;
    }
```

However, once a button is clicked and then a click occurs anywhere else on the page, the style disappears as expected.  Is there a way for the style to persist until another button is clicked specifically?

Comment: You'll need to use JS

Comment: darn....so no way to just use CSS?

Comment: AFAIK CSS cannot remember state and condition, but you can easily create CSS classes and apply conditionally using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Javascript might be needed to add or remove CSS classes as users click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without JS:

```css
input[name='btn-focus'] {
  display: none
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.btn:hover,
:checked+.btn {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="btn-focus" id="btn-focus1">
<label for="btn-focus1" class="btn">Button 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="btn-focus" id="btn-focus2">
<label for="btn-focus2" class="btn">Button 2</label>
```